# nmbd "Packet send failed" error

Tags: samba, arp, netbios

I'm desperately trying to get folder sharing over SMB working on my local network.
I'm running up-to-date arch linux and connecting over wifi using wicd. I have latest samba installed (4.10.4).

While it does work occasionally, it consistently breaks after a while, with the following errors spamming in my system logs:

```
Jun 18 21:22:02 zw.host kernel: neighbour: arp_cache: neighbor table overflow!
Jun 18 21:22:06 zw.host nmbd[24996]: [2019/06/18 21:22:06.027352,  0] ../../source3/libsmb/nmblib.c:917(send_udp)
Jun 18 21:22:06 zw.host nmbd[24996]:   Packet send failed to 192.168.1.139(47491) ERRNO=Invalid argument
Jun 18 21:22:06 zw.host nmbd[24996]: [2019/06/18 21:22:06.027442,  0] ../../source3/nmbd/nmbd_packets.c:1027(reply_netbios_packet)
Jun 18 21:22:06 zw.host nmbd[24996]:   reply_netbios_packet: send_packet to IP 192.168.1.139 port 47491 failed
Jun 18 21:22:06 zw.host kernel: neighbour: arp_cache: neighbor table overflow!
Jun 18 21:22:12 zw.host nmbd[24996]: [2019/06/18 21:22:12.069405,  0] ../../source3/libsmb/nmblib.c:917(send_udp)
Jun 18 21:22:12 zw.host nmbd[24996]:   Packet send failed to 192.168.1.139(47491) ERRNO=Invalid argument
Jun 18 21:22:12 zw.host nmbd[24996]: [2019/06/18 21:22:12.069518,  0] ../../source3/nmbd/nmbd_packets.c:1027(reply_netbios_packet)
Jun 18 21:22:12 zw.host nmbd[24996]:   reply_netbios_packet: send_packet to IP 192.168.1.139 port 47491 failed
```

I realize `nmbd` stands for netbios name resolution which I assume is a prerequisite for `smb` discovery, but was unable to find any information on the error. The `arp_cache` error appears in conjunction with the `nmbd` one, so I assume they are related. Regarding this error, I tried adjusting `net.ipv4.neigh.default` garbage collection values to no avail - although this makes no sense since I'm on a small local network with very few devices (<10).

The error seems to disappear if I reboot the system which is undesirable.

Comment: I have same error message on asus router nmbd.log whn I am trying to rsync samba share (ext HDD atached to router) to ext HDD attached to my PC. no solution yet.